# AlertDialog with Light Theme on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, themes

my App uses Holo Light which works fine, also on 2.3.3. But when it comes to an AlertDialog,
the dialog is still dark on 2.3.3.
I tried different themes on the ContextThemeWrapper, but none of them works.

This is my code to create the builder in onCreateDialog:

```
ContextThemeWrapper context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),  android.R.style.Theme_Light);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mydialog, null);
builder.setView(view)
       .setTitle(getActivity().getString(R.string.MyDialogCaption));
return builder.create();
```

I tried differnent values for the theme, even the ones from the AppCompat library, but the dialog is still dark. All activities are light as defined in the AndroidManifest:

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

How can I make this dialog light?

Answer (score 0):

In short, android 2.3 doesn't have AlertDialog.Light theme.
So I don't think you have anyway to use a system's light AlertDialog on android 2.3.

And if you have designed a good theme for your view, for example, R.style.light.
I'd suggest you to use

```
LayoutInflater.from(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),  R.style.light))
```

to get the inflater.

For me, I just use the dark dialog theme on android 2.3. And if you want to apply to your light theme, you can do as below:

1). define a AlertDialog.Light (other name would be ok), contains following items as AlertDialog.Holo.Light in api-14. (Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AlertDialog)

```
<item name="android:fullDark"></item>
<item name="android:topDark"></item>
<item name="android:centerDark"></item>
<item name="android:bottomDark"></item>
<item name="android:fullBright"></item>
<item name="android:topBright"></item>
<item name="android:centerBright"></item>
<item name="android:bottomBright"></item>
<item name="android:bottomMedium"></item>
<item name="android:centerMedium"></item>
```

2). defind your theme, and reference to the dialog theme

```
<item name="android:alertDialogStyle"></item>
```

But i think, let the alertdialog in android 2.3 dark, as it will take too much customization.
Here is the commit when I try to fix the android 2.3 light theme probolem in xprivacy:
https://github.com/liudongmiao/XPrivacy/commit/13762c

Answer (score 0):

You can use this project: **[AlertDialogPro](https://github.com/fengdai/AlertDialogPro)**. As the AlertDialogPro's API is totally the same as AlertDialog's, you don't need to do much work. Just include it to your project, and simply change AlertDialog to AlertDialogPro:

From:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
```

To:

```
AlertDialogPro.Builder builder = new AlertDialogPro.Builder(getContext());
```

And specify `AlertDialogProTheme.Holo.Light` theme to your app's theme with attribute "alertDialogProTheme":

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
  ...
  <item name="alertDialogProTheme">@style/AlertDialogProTheme.Holo.Light</item>
</style>
```

Then you can have a **Holo light** AlertDialog across **all versions** of Android.